# Hide or temporarily remove a child ViewController from a parentViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, container-view

(asking and self-answering, since I found no hits on Google, but managed to find a solution in the end by trial and error)

With iOS 5 and 6, Apple added some ugly hacks to make InterfaceBuilder support "embedded" viewcontrollers. They didn't document how those work, they only give code-level examples, and they only cover a limited subset of cases.

In particular, I want to have an embedded viewcontroller that is sometimes hidden - but if you try the obvious approach it doesn't work (you get a white rectangle left behind):

```
childViewController.view.hidden = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just create an IBOutlet to your container view and do

```
self.containerView.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

How they've done it appears to be a variation on the manual way that worked since iOS 2 (but which only supported views, not viewcontrollers) - there is a real, genuine UIView embedded into the parent (not mentioned in the source code examples - it's only added when you use InterfaceBuilder!).

So, instead, if you do:

```
childViewController.view.superview.hidden = TRUE;
```

...it works!

Also, counterintuitively, you can call this method at any time from viewDidLoad onwards - the "embed segue" hack from Apple is executed *before* viewDidLoad is called.

So you can do this on startup to have your childViewController start off invisible.

Comment: None of this is a big revelation. If you add a container view and look at its class, you will see that it's just a UIView, and that like any other UIView, it has a default white background color.

Comment: Apple's docs describe this differently. They don't mention the "extra" UIView. They also don't document the "embed segue" at all (it only appears in WWDC videos, so far as I can tell from googling). Anything undocumented suprises me :)

Comment: Well, I would agree that the documentation on this is definitely sparse.

Comment: If you are adding the view controller though IB, you actually see the embed segue.

Comment: @Jonah.at.GoDaddy yep. you see the segue. But it does NOT work like a normal Segue (c.f. it fires before viewDidLoad!). Does it require a containerview? Is the containerview only required by Xcode/NIB? :(

Comment: You saved me a lot of work adding and removing my embedded viewcontrollers just to hide/unhide them. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use This `[self.childviewController setHidden:YES];`

Comment: The docs say there's no such thing as "self.containerView". Where are you getting this from?

Comment: childviewController not containerView

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody will need to hide/show all child views or iterate over them:

```
func hideChildrenViews() {
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        (view as! UIView).hidden = true
    }
}

func showChildViews() {
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        (view as! UIView).hidden = false
    }
}
```